# C++ Bitwise operation?

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

Let's say i have an u_char array of bytes as below:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
u_char |hex_value|       |bit_size_in_array_position
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
bits[0] = 0xa0 -> 8 bits  8
bits[1] = 0xd3 -> 8 bits  16
bits[2] = 0xfd -> 8 bits  24
bits[3] = 0x6a -> 8 bits  32
bits[4] = 0xbc -> 8 bits  40
bits[5] = 0xe2 -> 8 bits  48
bits[6] = 0x04 -> 8 bits  56
bits[7] = 0x7f -> 8 bits  64
bits[8] = 0x06 -> 8 bits  72
bits[9] = 0x17 -> 8 bits  80
bits[10] = 0x5d -> 8 bits  88
bits[11] = 0xb7 -> 8 bits  96
bits[12] = 0x93 -> 8 bits  104
bits[13] = 0xea -> 8 bits  112
bits[14] = 0x08 -> 8 bits  120
bits[15] = 0x1c -> 8 bits  128
bits[16] = 0x4f -> 8 bits  136
bits[17] = 0x3a -> 8 bits  144
bits[18] = 0x00 -> 8 bits  152
bits[19] = 0xfa -> 8 bits  160
```

and i need to read `1 bytes` from the `140th bit` position of the `u_char bits[20];` array. If i am not wrong it has to have a hex value of `0xf3` but i can not get the right value of that point.

I used the below bitwise operation:

`((unsigned)(bits[16] & 0xF) << 8) + (unsigned)(bits[17] & 0xF0);`

I have just started to play with C++ and this is my very first attempt with bitwise operations.
What is wrong with this operation and how can i correct it?

Thank you!

Comment: And what result *do* you get?

Comment: `((unsigned)(bits[16] & 0xF) << 4) + (unsigned)((bits[17] & 0xF0) >> 4);` That should give you `0xF3`.

Comment: Thank you Igor for your help! Your suggestion worked well but can you tell me what is wrong with my operation?

Comment: With your operation you are getting 8 bits from bits[16] and 8 bits from bits[17], shifting by 8 the position of bits[16] your result will be a short (16bit) with bits[16] and bits[17], you need a single nibble (4bit) from bits[16] and a single nibble from bits[17], hence the bit shifts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.